Interceptor Logic Not Working Properly | Android
Does anyone know why this piece of code doesn't guarantee that the token is refreshed only once and made ready for subsequent calls (i occasionally get token not valid error) even though I've wrapped the critical section with Mutex to ensure other calls wait if a previous one is in the process of refreshing the token:
private fun proceedRequest(
       sessionManager: SessionManager,
       request: Request,
       chain: Interceptor.Chain,
       isProtectedCall: Boolean
   ): Response {
       if (isProtectedCall) {
           runBlocking {
               tokenRefreshMutex.withLock {
                   if (sessionManager.isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                       refreshAccessToken()?.let { token -> // will throw IOException if error
                           sessionManager.saveAccessToken(token.access)
                           sessionManager.saveRefreshToken(token.refresh)
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           val authorizedRequest = request.newBuilder()
               .addHeader(
                   "Authorization",
                   "${RaastinConstants.JWT_HEADER_TYPE}${sessionManager.accessToken}"
               )
               .build()
           val response = chain.proceed(authorizedRequest)
           when (response.code) {
               403 -> { // refresh token error
                   sessionManager.clearTokens()
                   return response
               }

               500 -> { // server error
                   return response
               }

               else -> return response
           }
       } else {
           return chain.proceed(request)
       }
   }

   private fun refreshAccessToken(): JWTTokenRefresh? {
       val requestBody = FormBody.Builder()
           .add("access", sessionManager.accessToken ?: "")
           .add("refresh", sessionManager.refreshToken ?: "")
           .build()
       Timber.d("Token refresh request, access: $sessionManager.accessToken")
       Timber.d("Token refresh response, refresh: $sessionManager.refreshToken")

       val request = Request.Builder()
           .url("${RaastinConstants.BASE_URL}v1/accounts/token/refresh/")
           .post(requestBody)
           .build()

       val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
       Timber.d("Token refresh response: $response")
       if (response.isSuccessful) {
           val json = JSONObject(response.body?.string() ?: "")
           response.close()
           return JWTTokenRefresh(
               access = json.getString("access"),
               refresh = json.getString("refresh")
           )
       } else {
           response.close()
           return null
       }
   }

